# SPARK : SCALA - org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'take'

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Spark is throwing AnalysisException when I try to run a query

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'take'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.;

This is the query I am trying to execute

```
spark.sql(s"""
    select
    status,
    sum(NEW) as new,
    concat_ws(", ", take(coll_set(NEW_GRP_ID), 3)) as new_excp_samples
    from
    (
        select
        distinct
        status,
        case when excp_status = 'NEW' then 1 else 0 end as NEW,
        case when excp_status = 'NEW' then grouping_id else null end as NEW_GRP_ID
        from source_data  
    ) group by status
    """)
```

I was able to run this very same query from one of my other job but it is failing now in a different job in the same env and this new job has never been completed successfully.

**New Spark session is created each time when I trigger this job**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this code:

```
take(coll_set(NEW_GRP_ID), 3))
```

There's no spark SQL function that takes a column and an integer as a variable, so my guess it's a  registered udf function, which can explain why it was working before when it's registered and now it didn't work, I'm guessing that the purpose of the method is to take 3 first element of a column of type list/array, so I implement the below udf function, also coll_set should be collect_set, you need to add this code before your query:

```
val take = udf((grp_id: Seq[String], n: Int) => {
  grp_id.take(n)
})
spark.udf.register("take", take.asNondeterministic())
```

Here's a sample code in scala:

```
val df = Seq(("1", "a"), ("1", "b"), ("1", "c"), ("1", "d"), ("2", "b"), ("2", "c")).toDF("status", "NEW_GRP_ID")

df.createOrReplaceTempView("source_data")

val take = udf((grp_id: Seq[String], n: Int) => {
  grp_id.take(n)
})
spark.udf.register("take", take.asNondeterministic())

spark.sql(
  s"""
select
status,
concat_ws(", ", take(collect_set(NEW_GRP_ID), 3)) as new_excp_samples
from df
group by status
""").show()

+------+----------------+
|status|new_excp_samples|
+------+----------------+
|     1|         c, b, a|
|     2|            c, b|
+------+----------------+
```